# How to manipulate excel files xlsm using python 3

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlrd, xlwt, xlsm

good afternoon.

I have a problem with my work and I can not solve it.

**First problem:** I need to read some values ​​in an xls file and place them in specific locations in an xlsm file daily.

- I can read the values, however I can not write to the xlsm file. Gives an error

**Second problem:** If I change xlsm to xls I can not just put the values ​​I need, it makes a copy of all information that has no original file.

I am using xlrd as xlwt libraries

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import easyxf
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = open_workbook('Y:/Operação/RDH/2017/01 Jan/RDH05JAN.xlsx')
sh = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
sh2 = rb.sheet_by_index(1)
sh3 = rb.sheet_by_index(2)
sh4 = rb.sheet_by_index(3)

wb = copy(rb)

ws = wb.get_sheet(0)
ws2 = wb.get_sheet(1)
ws3 = wb.get_sheet(2)
ws4 = wb.get_sheet(3)

print ("SUDESTE")
energia_armazenada_max_se = sh2.cell_value(rowx=6, colx=11)
print ("Valor: " + str(energia_armazenada_max_se))
ena_percent_mlt_se = format(sh2.cell_value(rowx=7, colx=7))
print ("Valor: " + str(ena_percent_mlt_se))
ena_total_mlt_se = format(sh2.cell_value(rowx=6, colx=7))

ws.write ( 1,0, 999999 )
ws.write ( 1, 1 , 999999 )

wb.save('Y:\TEMP\Hugo\Programação\Balanço Diário de Energia 2017.xls')
```

Comment: First problem: "gives an error" ... WHAT error? Second problem: I don't understand " If I change xlsm to xls I can not just put the values ​​I need, it makes a copy of all information that has no original file" ... please explain

Comment: John, thanks for answering. I need to get specific information from a file, not the entire document and put in another existing file, also in specific places. With xlsm extension. I do not get any error messages, but the xlsm file does not seem to work with the xlwt and xlrd modules. And when I use the xls only, it makes a copy of the entire original document and not just the information I want.

Comment: See http://www.python-excel.org/ for details of other software that may do some of what you want.